# Eclipse ==> Ant plugin?

Tags: eclipse, ant, plugins

Can anybody please tell me how i can add the ant plugin to eclipse?
Thanks

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Ant is integrated into eclipse. If you go to the Window menu, ant should be one of the views available to open.

Comment: Also, the quick access feature is very useful to find something in Eclipse, in this case: Ctrl+3, type Ant (Cmd+3 on Mac).

Comment: Actually, its not integrated into eclipse, its a part of the Java (or JEE) development tools. If you install for example eclipse for C/C++, you can install the Java tools (including Ant) via the update site of your respective eclipse version.

Comment: Plug-in Development Environment is the exact name of the plug-in to install manually. I prefer to download the minimal eclipse runtime binary and install only the plug-ins I need. Now I needed Ant and found this thread.

Answer (score 28):

Ant core is part of every Eclipse install but not the UI, that's part of the JDT package. However we can install the Ant UI (view + editor) component directly using Eclipse's P2 director through the command line as follows:

```
    $ cd <your eclipse install folder>
    $ ./eclipse -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director -repository http://download.eclipse.org/releases/kepler -installIU org.eclipse.ant.ui
    Installing org.eclipse.ant.ui 3.5.400.v20130514-1341.
    Operation completed in 19162 ms.
```

Note: make sure you adjust the '-repository' argument in the command to match your Eclipse release. The above will install the version from the Kepler release, even when running with Luna or Mars. If you accidentally installed the wrong version, uninstall it first by replacing '-installIU' with '-uninstallIU'. Otherwise installing the newer version will fail.

[image: Ant UI Installed]

Comment: This should be the accepted answer! It works fine on Windows too, it just doesn't print that status info and it appears to briefly launch Eclipse.

Comment: Seems this is the only way to install ant UI into C/C++ Eclipse version.

Comment: Glad this answer is helping :) -  I have actually leveraged the p2 director in a shell script to create my own version of Eclipse using the 64mb 'Platform Runtime Binary ' and only the plugins I need - very handy if I need to re-install / duplicate my setup.

Answer (score 3):

First Open Eclipse...then Follow steps...

1. Go to Help --> Install New Software...
2. You find Field ... Work With ... Paste Below Link and Press Enter...
   http://www.apache.org/dist/ant/ivyde/updatesite
3. Now You Got  : 1.   Apache Ivy library   and 2.    Apache IvyDE Eclipse plugins  ... choose select all option.
4. click Next and Agree and Finish

Enjoy Ant Apache Plugin...

Answer (score 1):

follow following steps -

1. download latest binaries file of ant form http://ant.apache.org
2. Unzip and place your workstation
3. Create a new environment variable called ANT_HOME = E:\apache-ant-1.8.2
4. Add E:\apache-ant-1.8.2\bin in PATH in environment variable
5. check on cmd ant -version

Comment: finally a strait answer

Comment: That was not what the OP was asking.

Answer (score -3):

**it not ant** that is installed by default with eclipse
but the **plugin of ant that latte you use ant directly from your id** in this Cass eclipse
so ant must be present in your system so the pugin can use it 
**to install ant in Ubuntu** use this command in a terminal 
***sudo apt-get install ant***

Comment: Not true. The `org.apache.ant` plugin contains the actual `ant` code.